# В какую папку грузить сайт в GoDaddy?

Tags: хостинг

Я до этого работал со многими хостами, но тут в ФТП столько папок!

Куда мне загрузить сайт и как потом открыть его через браузер?

Грузил в www/username/ потом запустил так:

```
 мой IP/www/username/index.html
```

но 404.

Кто подскажет?

Answer (score 1):

у Вас VPS? Попробуйте для начала проверить настройки Apache (раздел home - должна быть прописана директория расположения Вашего проекта). 
Это навскидку. Не хватает подробностей.